# Inserting the result of an IN subquery into separate columns

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table of `follower` and `followee` which holds two `user_id` values.

`user_id`s are mapped to a `username` and I need to get the matching `user_id`s from the supplied `username`.

To get the `user_ids` I have the query

```
SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username IN (username1, username2)
```

What I want to do is insert these values into the follower table, and I think I start with

```
INSERT INTO followers (follower, followee) ( SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username IN (username1, username2)
)
```

However, this queries results in two problems
1) how do I insure the correct result is the follower and followee
2) how do I take the result of the `SELECT` statement and put it into a format which mysql will accept as the values for the insert?

Comment: Can you also provide some sample data/expected out then I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your tables structures are but if username1 is the name of the follower and username2 is the of the followee, this query should help you :

```
INSERT INTO followers (follower, followee) 
SELECT follower.user_id, followee.user_id
FROM user AS follower 
INNER JOIN user AS followee ON (follower.user_id <> followee.user_id)
WHERE follower.username = username1
AND followee.username = username2
```

Comment: Thanks @David  I think I was just significantly over complicating things.